setting up a bluetooth network
I have a Lenovo laptop which will be my main PC on my boat.
On it I have OpenCPN which I use as a plotter. That gets its GPS from an external dongle.
I also have a Microsoft surface go 2. I would like to connect the two via Bluetooth so I can get the GPSinfo to the same OpenCPN program which is on my tablet.
Research led me to a program called virtual serial port emulator which I followed all directions for and it made the ports but when prompted to select the Bluetooth device to connect to it would not show my tablet even though it is connected, it did show a keyboard and a speaker which is connected.
Any pointers to doing anything in a better way would be great.

could you explain that plz

i apologize, as a 45yo english speaker that is quite readable. typos? do you mean the short hand for pc, gps. even used spell check and is correct beside abbreviations. there is no topic septations to require paragraphs. sorry i got lazy and did not capitalize. ill fix that one for ya. tell me what you do not understand and ill gladly clarify.

does this help?
